# Concatenate a char to every cell element - matlab

Tags: matlab, cell

In the code attached below the filesNames is a cell with the files names but without the fileFolder (char).

How can I concatenate them to a cell?

Thanks

Code"

```
fileFolder = fullfile('C:\Users\llx1\Desktop\oldData');
dirOutput = dir(fullfile(fileFolder,'*.xls'));
fileNames = {dirOutput.name}'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
fileNames = cellfun(@(idx) fullfile(fileFolder,idx),{dirOutput.name}','uni',0)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the fast respond